# Python login to chess.com with requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to read out out some of my stats from chess.com.  I am struggling to log in with python.

I am trying to follow the tutorial [here](http://kazuar.github.io/scraping-tutorial/)

I have identified the following tags from the login-page. `_username` as the username, `_password` as the password and `_token` as the hidden token.

My code:

```
session_requests = requests.session()

login_url = 'https://www.chess.com/login'
result = session_requests.get(login_url)
tree = html.fromstring(result.text)

token = list(set(tree.xpath("//input[@name='_token']/@value")))[0]

payload = {
    "_username": "ChristianSloper", 
    "_password": "mypasswordgoeshere", 
    "_token": token
}

result = session_requests.post( login_url, data = payload, headers = dict(referer=login_url), verify=True)
```

Unfortunately, I just get sent back to the login page.  I am very new to front end /web and would be very pleased for any help.

Comment: Just spy on a sucessful GET of the login page then POST to login - as done by a user with a browser, then replicate what gets sent on the POST. Using a Requests session will ensure cookies are handled, you need to make sure theheaders sent on the POST are the same/indistinguishable from what the browser sends. Use a spying app like the free and excellent Telerik Fiddler.

Comment: It’s possible that the login will always fail if the client doesn’t appear to be a browser.

Comment: Thanks for tip @barny. I wasn't able to read anything from Telerik, it all seems encrypted. (or i might be using Fiddler wrong, since i haven't used it before :-) )

Comment: You go to Fiddler options and configure https - it becomes a proxy (man in the middle) decrypting the communication. Of course you have to accept Fiddler’s certificate in the browser. But then you see all communication - headers, content. Fiddler invaluable for monitoring browser<>server communication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your payloads aren't entirely correct (there are a few things missing in it) and it appears that you are sending the POST request to the wrong URL, try this code:

```
session_requests = requests.session()

login_url = 'https://www.chess.com/login'
result = session_requests.get(login_url)
tree = html.fromstring(result.text)

token = list(set(tree.xpath("//input[@name='_token']/@value")))[0]

payload={"_username": "ChristianSloper", 
         "_password": "mypasswordgoeshere", 
         "login": '',
         "_target_path": "https://www.chess.com/home",
         "_token": token
        }

session_requests.headers.update(dict(referer=login_url))
result = session_requests.post("https://www.chess.com:443/login_check", data = payload, verify=True)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

you are posting to the wrong url the browser posts to "https://www.chess.com/login_check" not "https://www.chess.com/login" Also make sure to emulate a browser with a user agent. It would look something like this

```
    response = session.get(login_url, allow_redirects=True)  # gets the login url data
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")  # parses the html
    token_input = soup.find('input', {'name': '_token'})  # finds the token
    if token_input:
        token = token_input.get('value')
        # print("Token:", token)
    else:
        print("Token not found.")

    login_data = {"_username": "username",
                  "_password": "password",
                  "login": '',
                  "_target_path": quote(game_url),
                  "_token": token
                  }

    data_string = "&".join([f"{key}={value}" for key, value in
                            login_data.items()])  # formats the data into a string that can be sent to the server
    print(data_string)
    headers = {
        "User-Agent": UserAgent().random,
        "Referer": login_url
    }

    # Perform the login request
    login_post = session.post(login_post_url, data=login_data, headers=headers, allow_redirects=True, verify=True)
    print(login_post.status_code)
```

Try this code. Also hope this helps! Status code should be 302 as it redirects you to home or wherever.